# Plot showing the average

Tags: data-visualization

Found the following chart in a paper. I would like to know the name of this type of plot.

[image]

Comment: It's just a variation of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot

Comment: The question about the black points is intriguing. My reaction was "those are the data!" But a closer look shows that's incorrect, because (paradoxically) the violins all tend to show the greatest densities where the points are *scarcest*. I suspect this graphic has been seriously corrupted by *overplotting duplicate values,* especially at the apparent minimum near 1.63. If you do draw one, please make sure you indicate the extent of such overlaps: scale the points to reflect the amount of overlap, jitter them horizontally, or use sunflowers--but do *something* to eliminate this visual lie.

Comment: 'in a paper' is a poor reference, indeed no reference at all. People might be interested in the reference, if only to check whether the explanation there is as deficient as your question implies. The truncations at around 1.55 s are interesting.

Comment: Thanks. I can't read the paper myself (permissions) but the reference is now there.

Comment: @Nick I was able to download the PDF.  It looks like a gated site, but it isn't.  However, I couldn't find any information in the paper that is useful for answering this question, and so suggest not wasting your time by investigating it.

Comment: Edited the question. I'm only interested in the type of plot, which is a violin plot. I can take it from here. I've seen this type of plot before, but didn't know the name.

Comment: The detail of the black dots remains interesting, not least on how far the graph is misleading. It's possible that each mean -- as the plot shows the distributions of means -- is weighted by a sample size.

Comment: @user2974951 You have the answer in your comment. I'd consider fleshing it out slightly for a formal answer, which seems likely to be acceptable to the OP..